# How to pass parameters in React Function From 1 file to another

Tags: reactjs, import

I am newbie to reactjs and I would like to ask if it is possible to achieve this.

I have two files, I would like to pass the ID from Home.js to DataModel.js

Heres my code:

**DataModel.js**

```
const axios = require('axios');
const base_url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

function getUSers(id) {
    return axios.get(base_url + '/users/' + id)
}

export const getUSers = getUSers(id);
```

=================================

**Home.js**

```
import { getUSers } from './DataModels';

class Home extends Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);

        this.state = {
           records: ''
        }
   }

   render(){
         let id = 2;

         getUsers(id); // -----> How to pass this ID? 

         return (
             <div>
                 //Codes
             </div>
         );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your **DataModel.js** exists in the same origin `src` folder as your component. You can minimize your file by using some ES6 JavaScript.

```
import axios from "axios"

const base_url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

export const getUsers = (id) => {
    return axios.get(base_url + '/users' + id)
}
```

Then in **Home.js** you should call that function in `componentDidMount()` which is the React life-cycle method that is triggered after the component has first rendered (after first displaying the content).

```
import { getUsers } from './DataModels';

class Home extends Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);
        this.state = {
           records: ''
        }
   }

   componentDidMount(){
       let id = 2
       getUsers(id)
         .then((res) => {
             this.setState({
                 records: res.data
             })
         })
   }

   render(){
         return (
             <div>
                 //Codes
             </div>
         );
    }
}
```

Comment: Wew, you saved my day! Thanks Again @Christopher Ngo. :) :)

Comment: @larp you're very welcome! I'm just your friendly neighborhood stackoverflow user ^^

Comment: You should make React tutorials! hehe

Comment: @larp maybe one day when I'm not so camera-shy haha

Answer (score 2):

Add your fetch in [`componentDidMount()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount).

```
// Data Model
function getUsers(id) {
    return axios.get(base_url + '/users' + id) // return a promise
}

export const getUsers; // named-export function

// Component
class Home extends Component {
  ...
  async componentDidMount() {
    let id = 2; // for sample use only
    const users = await getUsers(id);
    console.log(users); // verify if fetched correctly
  }
  ...
}
```

Do **not** put any side effects  in `render()` that can alter the state of the component. Say if you store `user` in `state` variable.

```
this.state = {
  users: {},
}

async fetch = id => {
  const users = await getUsers(id)
  this.setState({ users }) // altering state.users
}

render() {
  fetch(2) // BAD: should not be inside render.
           // This will cause many re-renders if you alter state.users
}
```